# FInd out who invoked AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

My AWS lambda function is getting invoked my multiple places like api-gateway, aws-SNS and cloud-watch event. Is there any way to figure out who invoked the lambda function? My lambda function's logic depends on the invoker.

Another way to achieve this is having three different lambda functions but I don't want to go that way if I can find invoker information in a single Lambda function itself.

Comment: All of them will have different event object. Can't you check that?

Comment: @Marcin What specific information/attribute should I check in event object?

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the `event` object as all of the three services will have `event` of **different structure**.

For example, for CloudWatch Events I would check if there is a `source` field in the `event`.  For SNS I would check for `Records` and API gateway for `httpMethod`.

But you can check for any other attribute that is unique to a given service. If you are not sure, just print out to logs example events from your function for the three services and check what would be the most suited attribute to look for.

Comment: @Neel How did it go? Any progress?

Comment: Correct,  I am getting a different event structure for each invoker. Thanks!